# Traversing a Graph in Breadth First in Python Using a List of List

Tags: python, algorithm, list, graph, breadth-first-search

So I've seen breadth first search being implemented using dictionaries a lot. I just want to know if it's possible for a graph to be traversed using a list of list. And then returning the parent array. [the parents of each vertex.] If so, how? Say, I have an adjacency list like so

```
  G =  [[(1, None), (2, None)], [(0, None)], []]
```

where G is a directed and unweighted graph. Thus the NONE. Otherwise it'll have a number. vertex(0) is adjacent to both vertex(1) and vertex(2). Vertex(1) is adjacent only to vertex(0). Vertex (2) isn't adjacent to any.

Should I make a new list of vertices first? Should i get rid of the weight? I'm not sure how to approach this. Any help would be nice. thanks

Comment: If the nodes in the graph are numbers from 0 to n, that there's practically no difference in representing it as a list of lists or a dict of lists.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sure, either way is fine. You can represent your graph like this:

```
g = [[1, 2], [0], []]
```

then `g[g[j][0]]` gets you back the adjacency list of the vertex that comes first in the adjacency list of the `j`th element. There's no difference between a list of lists and a dictionary whose keys are `0,...,n` and whose values are a list of `int`s, but in my opinion a list is a saner idea unless a dictionary is necessary. There's no reason to have `None` for all your weights if nothing has a weight.

Note, however, that BFS will require you to keep track of whether or not a vertex has been visited, which you can do at the same time as keeping track of parents:

```
parents = [None, None, None]
```

You also typically want to keep track of the depth that you're currently at when you're visiting a node (unless you're only testing e.g. connectivity), which you can do with:

```
import collections
Vertex = collections.namedtuple("Vertex", ["idx", "depth"])
```

Now when you pop a vertex `v` off your queue, you go through each `u_idx` in its adjacency list. If `parents[u_idx] is None` (it hasn't been visited yet), then push `Vertex(u_idx, v.depth + 1)` on to your queue and mark `parents[u_idx] = v`.

Comment: thank you for your response! how do i keep track of the parent nodes?

Comment: @RylaiCrestfall I added in a solution.

Comment: @PatrickCollins, using parent array to keep track of visited vertices doesn't work well because the initial vertex is visited while it's parent is None.

Comment: @citxx Then set it's parent to be itself. That's a pretty minor problem.